# Manim Bot Issue

Tags: python, discord, timeout, bots, manim

I created a bot account to run this manim animation bot from [github](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/DiscordManimator):
Typing `python DiscordManimator.py` into my powershell successfully logs the manimator into my discord server.

When I try to have the bot produce the image

```
class OpeningManim(Scene):
   def construct(self):
      title = Tex(r"This is some \LaTeX")
      self.add(title)
```

the following error arises

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '1' time(s).
Type "TIMEOUT /?" for usage.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The bot is not compatible to run from Powershell, it is intended to be run from a Linux shell where `timeout` kills the command specified afterwards after the given amount of time.

It is not hard to work around that though: if you intend to run it from Windows without Docker, then edit https://github.com/ManimCommunity/DiscordManimator/blob/9bf2b753e402a316e1e5803e5ad77978a131b371/cogs/manimate.py#L105 and remove `timeout 120` so that the command starts with `manim ...`.

Note that this does means users in your server might be able to submit infinite loops or very performance heavy scenes to your bot, and to stop it from occupying your resources you'll need to step in manually.

Comment: This fixed the runtime error, but now I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Error: --config_file could not find a valid config file.: 'manim.cfg'`

Comment: I have the config.py file saved in the right place I'm pretty sure. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems unrelated and I do not see where `--config_file` is passed at any point. The discord bot's `config.py` also does not have anything to do with this, the error is complaining about a missing `manim.cfg` file; something that is included with every installation of Manim.

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't make sense. I feel like I must've not done something that the instructions do not mention. Unfortunately, there's no step-by-step resource I've seen that goes into making this bot work